# Cropping remote SVG with viewBox SVG Fragment identifier retains width

Tags: html, svg

I want to display only a part of the Yr.no metrogram SVG. To do the cropping, I use a fragment identifier, which almost does what I want:

```css
img {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.yr.no/en/content/2-6615464/meteogram.svg#svgView(viewBox(0,85,80,270))">
```

However, the image retains its width, which is now white padding, presumably because the svg retains its `width` and `height` attributes. I would like the image to only contain the part I cropped out. Can I somehow override the dimensions too?

Comment: Maybe CSS `object-position`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position

Comment: Try adding a width and a height to the image. In this case try  width="80" height="270". Also I see that the meteogram.svg has no viewBox attribute